# Angular watch doesn't always work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some functions in my controller and a watch which hide and show some elements on my page.

I initially created an object:

```
$scope.selectedItems = [];
```

With some functions I can select en deselect items:

```
$scope.selectAllItems = function(items){
        for(var i =0; i < items.length; i++){
            items[i].selected = true;
            $scope.selectedItems.push(items[i]._id);
        }
    }

$scope.deselectAllItems = function(items){
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        items[i].selected = false;
        $scope.selectedItems = [];
    }
}

$scope.inverseAllItems = function(items){
    $scope.selectedItems = [];
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        items[i].selected = items[i].selected ? false : true;
        if(items[i].selected)
            $scope.selectedItems.push(items[i]._id);
    }
}

$scope.selectItem = function(item){
    console.log(item.selected);
    if(item.selected){
        console.log(item._id);
        $scope.selectedItems.push(item._id);
    }else{
        console.log("hier2");
        if($scope.selectedItems.indexOf(item._id))
            $scope.selectedItems.splice($scope.selectedItems.indexOf(item._id),1)
    }
}
```

And a watch on `$scope.selectedItems`

```
$scope.$watch("selectedItems", function handleSelectedItemsChange(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log("$scope.selectedItems.length", $scope.selectedItems.length);
    if($scope.selectedItems.length > 1){
        $scope.multipleSelect = true;

        $('.itemStatus').toggleClass('hidden', true);

    }else{
        $scope.multipleSelect = false;
        $('.itemStatus').toggleClass('hidden', false);
    }
})
```

The problem is that the watch is not always triggered. After using the '`inverseSelection`' and '`deselectAll`' functions it is always triggered, but it will not be triggered after using '`selectAll`' and '`selectItem`' (select items one for one), but I didn't see any difference's in the way I push the entry's in the `selectedItems` array.

Can someone here help me?

Comment: As its an array, you should use `$watchCollection`

Comment: aaah. simple but that's indeed the solution. thanks!

Comment: @PankajParkar could you make that an answer.

Comment: @Alok I added it, Thanks ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To elaborate a bit more on the reason why it is happening on the two functions you mentioned: in the `inverseSelection` and `deselectAll` functions you initialize a new array.

```
$scope.selectedItems = [];
```

By default, `$scope.$watch` only compares for object reference, i.e. "is it still the same object". It does not care about the actual content. That's why the watch fires when you initialize a new empty array. In the other functions, you modify an already existing array, so the reference is the same. For the watch, it is the same object so it does not fire.

As others already mentioned there are two ways to solve it.

1. **$scope.$watch with objectEquality === true**

The third parameter of `$scope.$watch` tells angular to compare the content of the objects:

```
$scope.$watch("selectedItems", function handleSelectedItemsChange(newValue, oldValue){
    ...
}, true)
```

> When objectEquality == true, inequality of the watchExpression is determined according to the angular.equals function

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch

2. **$scope.$watchCollection**

In your case, this would be the better solution since it only "shallow watches" the object. This means it does work well for arrays but would not work for nested objects. For your array, it is better for performance than using `$scope.$watch` with `objectEquality`.

```
$scope.$watchCollection("selectedItems", function handleSelectedItemsChange(newValue, oldValue){
    ...
})
```

> for arrays, this implies watching the array items; for object maps, this implies watching the properties

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection

Answer (score 3):

You are Keeping a simple watch on array(shallow watcher), so it would only get fire when `reference` of an array gets change. So to make your watcher to fire on push operation on array. You could use `$watchCollection` which will fire when on `push` & on `removal` of an array element.

```
 $scope.$watchCollection("selectedItems", ...... )
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use "$watchCollection" or $watch with final parameter true.

ex `angular.$watch('collection', function() {}, true);`